# porting PCIe driver from Linux to OracleSolaris

Tags: solaris, device-driver, pci-e, opensolaris

I need to port a PCIe Linux driver to Oracle Solaris 11.2 (previously OpenSolaris). Before the driver was tested under kernel 2.6.32-36.

Fortunately, the driver was implemented in such a way that one portion is OS/platform specific (PCI registration, memory allocation etc.) and the other half was written in OS independent way, i.e. that part should be *relatively* easy to port.

My question is about Linux-specific portion, written according to steps in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/PCI/pci.txt, so I'm assuming Solaris might have similar approach? What should I pay attention to when porting to Solaris, what device driver parts are completely different in Solaris and nedd to be re-implemented then ported?

**UPDATE**
After reading several materials about Solaris driver model, I still don't understand the purpose and applicability of STREAMS framework, is it extension for character devices or for the network devices, eg. Ethernet cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solaris 11.2 driver documentation is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36860/index.html).

Here are some links that might also be useful:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-5789/
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/articles/write-dev-driver-jsp-140901.html
http://www.bolthole.com/solaris/drivers/TIPS.html
http://blog.csdn.net/hotsolaris/article/details/1763716

Comment: Thanks. I'm already reading "Writing device drivers in Solaris", I think more concrete questions will arise as I'm moving along.

Comment: @jillagre, are you aware of any forums/blogs specialized on Solaris OS and Solaris development topics?